# Internet Explorer HTTPS request aborted?

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, ssl

I installed a new signed certificate (SHA256 instead of SHA1) on my tomcat server. I initialized a new keystore like the old one. But after this I am unable to connect to my site via the Internet Explorer. (It's a intranet site and compatible modus for intranet sites is unchecked) The IE aborted the site request after ~200ms and show no error output/debug messages in the developer console.

All root and intermediate certificate in the chain are installed in the "windows certificate store".

In Chrome/Firefox all is fine and the certificate chain is valid.

Here is my tomcat config, but it is unchanged (I know it is not the best way to use the a keystore with default password).
server.xml:

```
...
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
...
```

PS: If I go back to the old keystore all works "fine", IE shows the "Certificate revoked" Output.

**Edit1:** I found a related entry in the system log

```
Protocolname: System
Source: Schannel
Entry-ID: 36887
It has received a serious warning: 80.
```

**Edit2:** Time server was not correct configured, but problem is still persistent.

**Edit3:** 
    System Information

```
Java: 1.6.0
Tomcat: 6.0.41.0
OS: SLES 11 SP 3
```

**Edit4:**
I used the tool [sslscan](https://software.opensuse.org/package/sslscan) to check the webserver, i guess the problem is a matching chipersuite

```
Prefered Server Cipher(s):
    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
```

Comment: IE has stricter revocation check compared to Chrome , Firefox. You could disable CR check in IE to see if that is the issue. https://ninite.com/help/errors/revocation.html ....... Note: It is not recommended but can do it for debugging.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is changed. I tried it with IE10.

Comment: You can check what all Cipher Suites are supported in IE  by version : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html

Comment: Thanks for you tips, i finally solved it.

Answer (score 0):

After I found out that my server only provides a chiper suite for SHA128 (DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA).

**Solution:**

To add ChiperSuits for SHA256 you have to install other policy files.
For IBM Java install the extended 
[unrestrictedpolicyfiles](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/sdkpolicyfiles.html)

For a Sun/Oracle Java Version use [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

After restarting the server all works fine.